# Expose AS2 Logic Apps with a custom URL

Tags: azure-logic-apps, edi

I want to expose a Logic App as an AS2 endpoint. I know how to do that with a combination of an HTTP trigger, AS2 Decode, and HTTP response.
But the issue is that I can't customize the URL of the Logic Apps.
What I'm looking for is the ability to have something like https://as2.mydomain.com.

What are my options for that:

- Use API Management to expose the Logic App as an API? -> Is it working with AS2 and in particular with the fact that I need to propagate AS2 headers and so on;
- Use Application Gateway? Or Azure FrontDoor? Or something else?

Comment: So I can tell what NOT to use... Azure Front Door... we just tried to use it with AS2 endpoints and it failed miserably... the 302 redirects were failing... looks to have something to do with resources and regions, Az FD is in a "global" region and the Az Logic Apps are in specific regions... management thru the Az portal could not be done and, unfortunately, we didn't have time to research Az Powershell options (the TRUE way to manage Az Resources).

Answer (score 1):

We finally used API Management to expose our AS2 endpoint and it works just great.